# Explain this simplification of how the $\lfloor n/2\rfloor=n/2 - 1$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm having trouble locating a rule and understanding how the floor of $n/2$ can simplify to $n/2 - 1$.

$$
T(n) \geq 2d \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor \lg \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + n
$$
$$
\geq 2d (\frac{n}{2} - 1) \lg \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + n
$$

Note:
This problem is solving for Ω regarding divide and conquer algorithms for the recurrence relation below. Solving for big O as the upper bound was straight forward in that T(n) has to be <= a solution of the from T(n) = cnlg(n). You will find CS student math to be a bit sloppy in that we will ignore the floor function and it will disappear.
$$
T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n     
$$
$$
T(1) = Θ(1)
$$
Solving for big O at the upper bound:
$$
T(n) \leq 2c \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor \lg \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + n
$$
$$
T(n) \leq 2c \frac{n}{2} \lg \frac{n}{2} + n
$$
$$
= cn(lg(n)  - 1) + n
$$
$$
\leq cnlg(n) \: where \: c \geq 1
$$
So, now I'm following a solution that solves for the lower bound Ω. Hence, I'm not able to follow how the solution to which this questions begins.

Comment: That appears to flat out be wrong, unless $d$ is negative.   Plugging in even $n$ shows trivially that the latter multiple is higher than the former

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the floor function, for any natural number $n\geq 2$,

$$ 1\leq\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \leq \dfrac{n}{2} < \left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2} \right\rfloor  +1$$

Therefore,

$$\dfrac{n}{2}-1<\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2} \right\rfloor  $$

Hence assuming $d$ is positive, we have,

$$d \log \left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right) \left(\dfrac{n}{2}-1\right) \leq d \log \left(\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right)\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2} \right\rfloor $$

Comment: The problem here involved the steps being linked by an inequality, so we don't actually need equals.  It's still wrong unless $d$ is negative though